# StickorStay JQuery function, error

Tags: javascript, jquery

Something is wrong but I cannot tell what it is.. Can somebody help me please? It's making all of my javascript/jquery fail, you can see it here: http://www.jacoinc.com/new/

I'm no longer getting an error however, it's not working...

```
var wHeight = $(window).height();

var stickorstay = function() {
    $('$supahslide').addClass('stay');
    if(wHeight >= 800) {
        $('#supahslide').addClass('stick', function() {
            $('#supahslide.stay').removeClass('stay');
        });
    } else {
        if(wHeight < 800) {
            $('#supahslide').addClass('stay', function() {
                $('#supahslide.stick').removeClass('stick');
            });
        };
    };
};

$(window).resize(stickorstay);stickorstay();
```

Comment: It's a good idea to describe the problem, even when including a link.

Comment: This is definitely too localized. A bunch of syntax errors..

Comment: Have you looked at the JS error console? It points at the line where you have the error. The error message is not the most intuitive but what it means is that `function foo{}` is not valid syntax.

Comment: On an unrelated note, the custom `::-webkit-scrollbar` you're using does not look good.

Comment: yeah i didnt want to use it but the client wanted it for whatever reason, I haven't really worked on it much... i will fix it

Comment: Don't for get about [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) - you can always run jsLint to get some help if the error console doesn't lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function syntax is incorrect:

```
$(function stickorstay() { // missing () in your code
  // ...
});
```

The JavaScript error console (in Chrome) clearly pointed that out to me when I tried your page.  That's the first thing to check when you've got such problems.

Answer (score 2):

There's a syntax error, indeed.

You declared your function in a wrong way, at the line 26 of your JS file.

In JS you can declare a function in two ways:

```
stickorstay = function() {
    ...
}
```

Or

```
function stickorstay() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Doesn't matter; **jQuery is JavaScript**.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you are missing some `()`s:

```
var wHeight = $(window).height();

$(function stickorstay(){
    $('$supahslide').addClass('stay');
    if(wHeight >= 800) {
        $('#supahslide').addClass('stick', function(){
            $('#supahslide.stay').removeClass('stay');
        });
    } else {
        if(wHeight < 800) {
            $('#supahslide').addClass('stay', function(){
                $('#supahslide.stick').removeClass('stick');
            });
        };
    };
});

$(window).resize(stickorstay);stickorstay();
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, maybe you meant `$('#supahslide')` not `$('$supahslide')`?